# Error in Virtual Box: Failed to open a session for the virtual machine

Tags: terminal, error, virtualization, virtualbox

I want to install Ubuntu 20.10 on Virtual Box 6.1.18, when I create the virtual machine is okay so I press start but when I want to search the ISO file this error appears to me.

[image]

I saw different solutions in the terminal for Windows, but any for Mac helped me. Downgrade Virtual Box isn't an option because my professor requires this version.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is just choose your ISO file not from start button, instead choose from Settings/Storage/Controller: IDE

Comment: WTF....I was looking everywhere for a solution and couldn't find why is this happening. Thanks for the quick solution :) (Hope this bug will be fixed!)